# Save form input values on Page1 and restore them when go to Page2 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have this simple reg form on Page1, which redirect user for Page2 which have advanced reg form:

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="signup-field" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" size="40" class=""    id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" size="40" class="" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
  <input type="checkbox" name="acceptance" value="1" class="" >
  <input class="sign-up-button" type="submit" onclick="parent.location='page2.html'" value="SIGN  UP NOW!">
</form>
```

So I need to save these 4 inputs value when user click "SIGN  UP NOW!" button and when it redirect user to Page 2 form, values 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email' and  'checkbox' must be already filled in Page2 form.

I've tried this code on page1 for save data in SessionStorage:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.signup-field .sign-up-button').click(function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("first_name", document.getElementById('first_name').val);
    sessionStorage.setItem("last_name", document.getElementById('last_name').val);
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", document.getElementById('email').val);
  });
});
```

And this code on page2 to restore:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('first_name') == "first_name") {
    return;
  }

  var first_name = sessionStorage.getItem('first_name');
  if (first_name !== null) 
    $('#ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-first-name').val(first_name);

  var last_name = sessionStorage.getItem('last_name');
  if (last_name !== null) 
    $('#ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-last-name').val(last_name);

  var email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
  if (email !== null) 
    $('#user_email').val(email);
});
```

However it's not working for me. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `However it's not working for me.` - Can you be more specific? Side note - better to create a single object in this case that contains all the properties with one entry into the session storage, it makes using it a little easier and your code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exists:

```
 document.getElementById('email').val
```

Vanilla JS syntax should be:

```
  document.getElementById('email').value;
```